# How to enable logging mechanism for tests in TestCafe framework

Tags: testing, logging, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am looking for a way to have a logging mechanism in my TestCafe framework where in i can enable INFO, ERROR logs for the particular test runs and logs to be written into a log file.
I explored and could not find a way to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to `console.log` wherever needed in your code and redirect the TestCafe command-line to a file: `testcafe chrome tests > tests.log`

Comment: In concurrent execution, is there any way to detect which console log is for which test?

Comment: @anyone.can.test There is a way retrieving the test name from the TestController that is mentioned in this issue (https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2826#issuecomment-520950150). I would suggest wrapping console log and prefixing the log messages with the test name